# How to vertically center align Multi-Line-Text on Canvas (in NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to *vertically* center align multi-line text on a canvas, using [canvas-multiline-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-multiline-text) on top of the npm module `canvas`. I cannot figure out how to (programmatically / automatically) vertically center the text.

The text might be 1 word or it might be a sentence with 10+ words. Is there a way to figure out its height and calculate the `y` position accordingly?

Note: *I am **not in a browser**, I am using node.js.*

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { registerFont, createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
const drawMultilineText = require('canvas-multiline-text')

const width = 2000;
const height = 2000;
let fontSize = 250;

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

//Filling the square
context.fillStyle = '#fff'
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

//Text Styles
context.font =  "normal 700 250px Arial";
context.textAlign = 'center'
context.textBaseline = 'middle';
context.fillStyle = '#000' 

//Drawing Multi Line Text
const fontSizeUsed = drawMultilineText(
    context,
    "Hello World, this is a test",
    {
        rect: {
            x: 1000,
            y: 1000, // <-- not sure what to put here / how to calculate this?
            width: context.canvas.width - 20,
            height: context.canvas.height - 20
        },
        font: 'Arial',
        verbose: true,
        lineHeight: 1.4,
        minFontSize: 100,
        maxFontSize: 250
      }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this as an answer as I can't comment yet, but the module you are using has no support for this. What you can do is modify the module (or just copy the function into your own code). The function has a variable y which stores the height of the text. You can initialize the variable outside of the for loop so that you can use it when drawing the text. Then you can subtract opts.rect.height from your new y variable and divide by two to get the correct offset, now the text will be centered in that y variable you specify when calling the function. Oh and finally get "context.textBaseline = 'middle';" as the module you use makes it calculations assuming a bottom baseLine. Here is the final code for the drawMultiLineText function

```
...
const words = require('words-array')(text)
if (opts.verbose) opts.logFunction('Text contains ' + words.length + ' words')
var lines = []
let y;  //New Line
...
var x = opts.rect.x;
y = fontSize; //modified line
lines = []
...
if (opts.verbose) opts.logFunction("Font used: " + ctx.font);
const offset = opts.rect.y + (opts.rect.height - y) / 2; //New line, calculates offset
for (var line of lines)
    // Fill or stroke
    if (opts.stroke)
        ctx.strokeText(line.text.trim(), line.x, line.y + offset) //modified line
    else
        ctx.fillText(line.text.trim(), line.x, line.y + offset) //modified line

...
```

This module you use isn't exactly the cleanest code (uses var instead of let, has a dependency just to split a string into words), so I would highly recommend you rewrite this function yourself. But those should be the required changes in order for it to center the text.

EDIT: After looking more closely at this dependency's code, it looks like there are more mistakes then I initially thought, the code treats height like the bottom of the rectangle, not like height. To fix this remove opts.rect.y from the line that assigns y, and add it to the offset variable (I already made these changes to the code)

Comment: woah, thanks a bunch for this. looks like you really looked into this. i'm a beginner though, and I am not 100% sure what value I should put for my variable `y` in my own code now? It seems I still need to calculate this somehow, or am I mistaken?

Comment: All the code I put is just modifications to the code of the dependency you used [canvas-multiline-text](https://gitlab.com/davideblasutto/canvas-multiline-text/-/blob/master/index.js). Although some would consider it unethical, I would reccomend just putting that code in your own program isntead of using a dependency, then making the changes I specified, I include lines near the modified lines to show you where they are, but the exact line numbers where you should makes changes are line 33, line 45, line 76, line 81, and line 83

Comment: yes, i got that, already made the changes. but i'm perplexed as to how to center the text now using this module, since it expects a `y` variable for the `rect` value and i don't know what to put in there, since it seems like i need to know the height of the text in order to know the `y` value. If I just put `x: 1000, y: 1000` (the whole canvas is 2000x2000) it gives me the correct result for `x` (as before), but still not the correct result for `y`.

Comment: You need to specify a height as well, and it should center the text between y and y + height. If it doesn't let me know as I kinda just wrote this code on the spot and didn't have the time to actually test it. 

EDIT: So looking at your code you use the canvas height as the height, if you want the text in the middle of the canvas simply use y: 0 and the canvas height. Or y: 20 and the canvas height - 40. If you don't like this method, I'm sure you are smart enough to modify the code to use topY and bottomY instead of y and height.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply, sorry for not being able to get it working. using `y: 0` and `height: context.canvas.height` does not vertically center it, it's horizontally centered, but at the top.

Comment: I just tested it myself and it works fine, centers the text vertically.